# Dereferencing a reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dereference

I'm reading "The C++ Programming Language (4th edition)" and I ran into this:

```
template<class C, class Oper>
void for_all(C& c, Oper op) // assume that C is a container of pointers
{
    for (auto& x : c)
        op(*x); // pass op() a reference to each element pointed to
}
```

So from what I understand, we're iterating through `c` and getting a reference to `x`, which is the current iteration. `x` is then passed to the function call operator of `op`, but it is dereferenced first? Why would `x` be dereferenced?

Comment: See the comment where it says that `C` is a container of pointers. Apparently `op()` doesn't want a pointer, it wants the value that the pointer points to. So you have to indirect.

Comment: I Googled "dereferencing a reference" word for word after reading that same excerpt of code! Glad to see I'm not the only one who made this mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said in a comment in the posted code:

> ```
> // assume that C is a container of pointers
> ```

That means `x` is a reference to a pointer. `*x` evaluates to be the object that pointer points to.

`op` must expect an object or a reference to an object, not a pointer to an object.

Comment: Well that explains it. By the way, the code is straight from the book and is not mine. I guess the comment went over my head.